# Powershell send-mailmessage logs

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, command

I need to debug `Send-MailMessage` command. In linux, I can see the logs of sending mail, via `tail -f`. There is an option to see the logs of this command? I want to send mail to an external domain, it runs but without any status.

Answer (score 2):

No return code usually means SMTP 2xx or: "the SMTP server accepted it". The CMDlet itself won't generate any output, as you can read [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6#outputs). If you have access to it, you can debug the mailflow on the corresponding mailserver.

If something went wrong, `Send-MailMessage` would output *your* SMTP server error code in your powershell window, like: `5.7.54 SMTP; Unable to relay recipient in non-accepted domain` OR the receiving SMTP server would return a mail with the bounce message to the `-From` address, like: `550 5.1.10 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipientNotFound; Recipient not found by SMTP address lookup` (not all servers behave like this).